# Export to CSV turns & " < > ' characters to ascii

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, csv

I have a button on my webpage that allows users to export a data table to CSV so that it can be opened in Excel. The problem is that some entries in the table (in particular the 'comments' column) contain special characters. The characters listed in the title are converted to ASCII when I export and open the data in Excel. Is there anywhere in my code that I can prevent this from happening, or would it have to be something the users deal with themselves? 
Here is the function that does the exporting:

```
 public void ExportToCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string strFileName = "GridViewExcel_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".csv";
        builder.Append("Date,High,Low,Average,Freeze Index, Sum FI, Thaw Index, Sum TI,Conditions, Comments" + Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string date = "=" + "\"" + row.Cells[0].Text + "\"";
            string high = row.Cells[1].Text;
            string low = row.Cells[2].Text;
            string average = row.Cells[3].Text;
            string fi = row.Cells[4].Text;
            string sumfi = row.Cells[5].Text;
            string ti = row.Cells[6].Text;
            string sumti = row.Cells[7].Text;
            string conditions = "\"" + row.Cells[8].Text + "\"";
            string comments = "\"" + row.Cells[9].Text + "\"";
            builder.Append(date + "," + high + "," + low + "," + average + "," + fi + "," + sumfi + "," + ti + "," + sumti + "," + conditions + "," + comments + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName);
        Response.Write(builder.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: "are converted to ASCII" <-- can you explain what you mean? What would they be if not ASCII? (Maybe you can give an example of what's happening and how it's different from what you want.)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean they are being encoded as "&gt;" and "&lt;"? If so try adding `Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF32;`

Comment: @RyanPeters, that's exactly what's happening, but adding that line didn't change it (I tried in several different places). Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I am going to guess the data is already encoded as you write the data. You need to decode it when appending.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TyCobb Thanks so much, that fixed it. If you want the points, add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is encoded in the GridView so that it can correctly display on the page. In order to properly use the data for the CSV, you need to decode it.

You can use the [HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do this

```
var comments = $"\"{HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[9].Text)}\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFileName);

    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

    Response.Write(builder.ToString());
    Response.End();
```